# How to clear a textfield's value and clear the focus at the same time?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am not sure if it's bug about FocusManager or TextField or something else. If I try to set the TextField's value and clear the focus of a TextField at the same time (i.e. within a button click), the setting of the TextField's value would not work.

In the following code, after I type something in the TextField, clicking the "reset and clear" button only clears the focus from the TextField, but the value of the TextField does not change. If I click the button again, it does change the value of the TextField. It seems to me I can do either one but not both at the same time.

P.S. Add a delay right before the clearFocus would make it work, of course then whole lambda has to be wrapped inside a scope launch.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    ResetAndClearTextField()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
private fun ResetAndClearTextField() {
    val (textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(
        TextFieldValue("")
    ) }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    Column {
        TextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = setTextFieldValue
        )

        Button(onClick = {
            setTextFieldValue(TextFieldValue(""))
            focusManager.clearFocus()
        }) {
            Text("reset and clear")
        }
    }
}
```

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testing.myapplication"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: The same code works for me. Can you check if the issue is due to some other code? Try this composable in a new project.

Comment: Maybe this could shed some light: https://codepen.io/chrisza/pen/jOGrWwK

Comment: Abhimanyu, I thought it's an emulator but it's not. I created a new emulator API 30 Pixel 4XL. I have also tried a real device Pixel 3 Android 12. Same thing happened. I put all my gradle files and surrounding code in the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using scope to wrap the `focusManager.clearFocus()` did not really work around the problem. It doesn't clear the focus at all but it would still respect the `setTextFieldValue(TextFieldValue(""))`

A real workaround is reverse the line, so clear the focus before setting the TextFieldValue.

```
focusManager.clearFocus()
setTextFieldValue(TextFieldValue(""))
```